# Deploying a PHP and Node JS project

Tags: php, node.js, deployment, openshift

My project uses mostly PHP but I have also used Node JS  for chat and canvas applications.

Now I am trying to deploy same via openshift (Red hat) but I think I can either use PHP or Node JS for deployments. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

If not , how can I deploy same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use OpenShift you would need to either split your application into two applications, or possibly create a custom OpenShift cartridge.

Comment: I would try that .Thanks!

Comment: Now on my local machine I had to different Node Js applications on separate ports one for chat and one for canvas drawing. I had used different ports on my local machine.Is it possible to deploy NodeJS applications on any other port apart from 8080.I am not sure if using any other cartridge for my 2nd NodeJS app would help(any that allows NodeJS deployments).Please let me know if there is a simpler way to approach same.

Comment: You will only be able to have one application per server/gear on OpenShift, and it will be bound to the port OpenShift makes available to you, which is usually 8080. That's why you can't have PHP and NodeJS both running on the same server on OpenShift. If you need them both on the same server, then OpenShift is not going to be a good fit for your application.

Comment: I  tweaked my code a little and  was finally able to deploy as 2 separate applications one for PHP and 1 for Node JS.